# Node features matrix with Networkx

Tags: python, machine-learning, smiles, drug-design

I built a function to generate graphs from smiles strings using networkx, inserting various features on the nodes. This is the code:

```
def mol_to_nx(mol):
    G = nx.Graph()
    
    for atom in mol.GetAtoms():
        G.add_node(atom.GetIdx(),
                   atomic_num=atom.GetAtomicNum(),
                   dg=atom.GetDegree(),
                   charge=atom.GetFormalCharge(),
                   hyb=atom.GetHybridization(),
                   is_aromatic=atom.GetIsAromatic(),
                   Hs=atom.GetTotalNumHs(),
                   rad=atom.GetNumRadicalElectrons,
                   ring=atom.IsInRing(),
                   chirality=atom.GetChiralTag())
        
    for bond in mol.GetBonds():
        G.add_edge(bond.GetBeginAtomIdx(),
                   bond.GetEndAtomIdx(),
                   bond_type=bond.GetBondType())
        
    return G
```

Now my question is: if I convert a smiles to graph G (e.g. `G=mol_to_nx('COC(=O)C=CN1CC1')`), is there a way to compute the node features matrix, where the rows are the nodes and the columns are the attributes I entered with `G.add_node`? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can get a list of lists of the node features like this:

```
g = mol_to_nx(Chem.MolFromSmiles('CCC'))
[list(g.nodes[n].values()) for n in range(g.number_of_nodes())]
```

but you will note that the features aren't all of the same type - some are integers, some are objects from RDKit. That means it won't look like a numpy matrix.